# MQMessage.ReadString gives error "Unable to read beyond the end of the stream in mscorlip"

Tags: vb.net, ibm-mq, bytebuffer, mq

With the following code:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength))
Dim InfoMsg As String = SmqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength)
```

The first line works fine and writes the MQMessage to the console but the second line gives an exception:

> Unable to read beyond the end of the stream in mscorlib

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MQMessage.ReadString(length)` advances the cursor in the message body by `length` bytes. For example if the message body length is 100 bytes, the first `ReadString(50)` will advance the cursor to `51st` byte so that the next `ReadString` call will read from `51st` byte.

In your case, the first statement `System.Console.WriteLine(mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength))` is reading the entire message body. Since the entire message has been read and cursor advanced beyond the message length, the second statement `Dim InfoMsg As String = SmqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength)` throws exception.

You can change the code as below

```
Dim InfoMsg As String = SmqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength)
System.Console.WriteLine(InfoMsg)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shashi, it fix the issue.